# How to update a label's caption on another user form?

Tags: vba, excel

I am using VBA to `Show` a `userform`.
On this form, I have buttons to open another `userform` (`AddAmountForm`).
When I click on the button to open `AddAmountForm` I also want to update the caption for a label that is on `AddAmountForm`.

Here is what I've tried this on the first userform:

```
Private Sub AssocDuesAddbtn_Click()
    AddAmountForm.Show
    With AddAmountForm
        .AddName.Caption = "Assoc. Dues"
        .Repaint
    End With
End Sub
```

However, this doesn't update the caption, it remains the same.

There will be several buttons that will open this second userform and each one will need to update the label to something different based on what each button is supposed to be updating.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just write `AddAmountForm.AddName.Caption = "Assoc. Dues" | AddAmountForm.Show`. I do this all the time in a recent app I built and it works perfectly. (Pipe is line break).

Comment: @ScottHoltzman That was it, I had them in the wrong order. Switching the order so that I'm showing after I update the caption did it. Put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Mike. Accept @Mat'sMug answer. It's a more detailed how and why of what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AddAmountForm.Show
```

This [displays the *default instance*](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) of the `AddAmountForm` form, modally. This means the next instruction will only execute **after** the form is closed.

You probably mean to change its label *before* you show it:

```
With AddAmountForm
    .AddName.Caption = "Assoc. Dues"
    .Show
End With
```

That said, using a form's *default instance* is going to bite you in the rear end, one day or another. Forms are objects, treat them as such:

```
With New AddAmountForm
    .AddName.Caption = "Assoc. Dues"
    .Show
End With
```

If the caption is a compile-time constant (a string literal is a compile-time constant expression), there's no reason to assign it at runtime - just set the label's caption in the form designer's *Properties* toolwindow (F4).

Comment: Thank you! I will take most of your answer and use it. However, I am setting the caption of this label with a different caption depending on which of 12 buttons are clicked so I can't just set the caption in the label's properties.

Comment: @Mike yeah I figured your code was simplified. If you want to learn more advanced concepts and eventually write proper, unit-testable, object-oriented code in VBA, read that article I linked to =)